# spring boot: Split application.yml file into multiple files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, yaml

I have an `application.yml` something like this

```
app:
 mappings:
  - name: "abc"
    state: "MH"
    age: "18"
  - name: "bcd"
    state: "MH"
    age: "18"
  - name: "xyz"
    state: "MP"
    age: "20"
```

I'm reading the property using `@ConfigurationProperties` to a dto.

What we want is to split this `application.yml` into multiple files to make it more readable and manageable as this list could be very long.

something like this

```
app:
 mappings:
  - application-state-mh.yml
  - application-state-mp.yml
```

application-state-mh.yml

```
key:
  - name: "abc"
    state: "MH"
    age: "18"
  - name: "bcd"
    state: "MH"
    age: "18"
```

application-state-mp.yml

```
key:
  - name: "xyz"
    state: "MP"
    age: "20"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use `spring.profiles.include` ? : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles

Comment: It is unclear to me if you want to know how to split up a YAML file containing one document into multiple files, each containing a document, or if you want to know how spring can read multiple files (in which case the tag [tag:yaml] would be inappropriate for this question).

Comment: @Anthon I have this requirement to split up a YAML file containing one document into multiple files. Also as i'm using spring boot so wanted to understand how we could map that to a java object

Comment: @shubhamsachan I don't know about spring boot, but splitting the YAML file is IMHO best done using a scripting language. I can provide an answer in Python if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2 year old problem which I encountered while looking for a similar use case. Hope this helps others. 
Unfortunately Spring doesn't support binding multiple prefixes with one Pojo. So our objective should be to generate one common Yaml at build time while we can maintain multiple fragments for maintainability and readability.
What you can do is to utilize [*maven-antrun-plugin*](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) to merge all your yaml files under a given resource directory into one, say

> application-states-all.yaml

and this should be the single *custom profile* to be included in your application.properties, like below.

```
spring.profiles.group.dev = states-all
```

Make sure, you maintain the order. for example, the top elements should be in the file which appears at top, alphabetically and the rest of the fragment should just have the child elements.

*application-states-mh.yaml*

```
app:
 mappings:
  - name: "abc"
    state: "MH"
    age: "18"
  - name: "bcd"
    state: "MH"
```

*application-states-mp.yaml*

```
  - name: "xyz"
    state: "MP"
```

The part yaml files should maintain the Tab spacing, assuming they have nth order elements in a hierarchy. See *application-states-mp.yaml* above for reference.

Add a plugin in your POM file, if you're working with maven. The execution should happen at *prepare-resources* stage. The other fragment yamls too will be copied along with the common one but there is no harm as we're only activating *states-all* profile. But if you're concerned about final build size, you can define *[filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)* to exclude the fragment files.

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <concat destfile="${project.build.directory}/classes/config/application-states-all.yaml">
                        <fileset file="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/application-states-*.yaml" />
                </concat>
              </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```